# mysql stored procedure query advice

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that takes some arguments, one of the arguments is a list of 'car names' . for example

```
CALL `car_list_inventory`(1,"'Honda','Nissan','BMW','Toyota'");
```

The result of the stored procedure returns the name of the car names that are currently available for example if
I was to run the procedure the results would be

```
store  cars_available   
----  ----------------          
1      Honda, BMW
```

part of the query that determines available cars is

```
SELECT store, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cars.model) AS cars_available 
FROM cars 
JOIN cars_avail ON cars.id = cars_avail.id_ref
WHERE cars.id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

What I want to do is add a second part which would return cars that are not available, for example, the whole result should look like

```
 store  cars_available    cars_not_available
 -----  ----------------   ---------------- 
    1      Honda, BMW        Nissan, Toyota
```

Could this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

To get the non-available cars:

```
SELECT store, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cars.model) AS cars_not_available
FROM cars
LEFT JOIN cars_avail ON cars.id = cars_avail.id_ref
WHERE cars_avail.id_ref IS NULL
GROUP BY store
```

You can also use `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT store, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cars.model) AS cars_not_aveilable
FROM cars
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id_ref FROM cars_avail)
GROUP BY store
```

To get both in a single query, you can do:

```
SELECT store,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN cars_avail.id_ref IS NOT NULL
                         THEN cars.model
                    END) AS cars_available,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN cars_avail.id_ref IS NULL
                         THEN cars.model
                    END) AS cars_not_available
FROM cars
LEFT JOIN cars_avail ON cars.id = cars_avail.id
GROUP BY store
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I dont think this works for my situation. Im kind of hoping for a simple solution just like 'not in' or something similiar to it. The result is giving me for your query is null

Comment: I've added the `NOT IN` version of the first query.

Comment: How do you map the procedure parameter to multiple rows in a database?

Comment: I assumed you'd already solved that problem for getting the list of available cars.

Comment: no, i can get the available cars but not the cars_not_available. I am trying to figure this out since it is not my code but a school project

Comment: How are you getting the available cars from that comma-separated list?

Comment: ok,I believe this is how it works: I pass a list of cars as a parameter in the stored procedure. There is a table call cars_avail where it has a list of available cars(for each row there is a car) so thats how I am getting the available cars from the join clause but I am not sure how to get the not_availabe_cars from the parameter I am inputting

Comment: MySQL doesn't have anything that turns a list like that into a table to join with. How are you currently doing that in your procedure?

Comment: ok I am going to try to explain it. There are 2 tables. car table has an id which references multiple rows on car_avail table. car_avail_id may have the same id but each of them has its own different car name but it still mapped to the car table . Overall what the stored procedure is doing is inserting data into a table and displaying the information back to the user. Its basically like processing an order.

Comment: Don't explain, SHOW. Update your question with the current procedure that finds the available models. Once you do that, I can explain how to modify it to find unavailable models.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make your problem fit into an API you have already chosen - which is the wrong way to find a solution. Especially when you are trying to break one of the fundamental rules of relational databases: an attribute (in this case the procedure parameter) should never contain more than one value.

The right way to solve the problem of a variable argument list using SQL is to put the list of values into a table and do a join. You might achieve this by parsing a single string to split out the values, but I'm guessing that you don't provide raw MySQL access to your users - hence it's much simpler to do the inserts from whatever you **are** using to bridge access, then....

```
INSERT INTO search (session, model, created)
VALUES
(CONNECTION_ID(), 'Honda', NOW()),
(CONNECTION_ID(), 'Nissan', NOW()),
(CONNECTION_ID(), 'BMW', NOW()),
(CONNECTION_ID(), 'Toyota', NOW());

SELECT store, SUM(IF(cars.model IS NULL, 0, 1)) AS matches, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(cars.model) AS available,
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF(cars.model IS NULL, search.models, NULL)) AS notavailable
FROM search 
LEFT JOIN cars
ON search.model=cars.model
AND cars,stock>0
WHERE search.session=CONNECTION_ID()
GROUP by store
ORDER BY matches;

DELETE FROM search
WHERE session=CONNECTION_ID();
```